# How to write unique log file for each instance of tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, java.util.logging

There are two instances i.e. lisxyz and lisabc and webapplication deployed on them points to same file mount to write the log file. How could I generate log file for each of these instance i.e. something like `log_lisxyz_{timestamp}.log` - which contains only lisxyz-specific logs and `log_lisabc_{timestamp}.log` for lisabc-specific logs.

Which approach (default tomcat internal logging- JULI or log4j) is suitable and has more control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I generate log file for each of these instance

Per [Tomcat JULI](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html) you can place a `logging.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes`:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = ${classloader.webappName}_.
```

By default the [`org.apache.juli.FileHandler`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html) will add the timestamp after the `prefix` but before the `suffix`.

> Which approach (default tomcat internal logging- JULI or log4j) is suitable and has more control ?

Log4j is covered in the Tomcat documentation too.  It will have more support for date patterns in the file name.  I would think that either would work for the requirements given.